# Display time stamp and save the screenshot in iphone memory

Tags: ios, iphone, applescript, filemaker, applescript-objc

```
set dFolder to "~/Desktop/tcapture/"
set theCurrentDate to current date

do shell script ("mkdir -p " & dFolder)

set i to 0 

repeat 1 times  
    do shell script ("screencapture " & dFolder & "fr-" & i & theCurrentDate &".tiff") 
    delay 10 -- Wait for 10 seconds. 
end repeat
```

above is my applescript that captures screen and stores in a folder called tcapture at desktop in mac
i need to store in FILEMAKER DATABASEIN IPHONE with timestamp kindly explain clearly

Comment: You want to take a screenshot of the Mac and store it directly on the iPhone?

Comment: i want to take screenshot on iphone while running this script in iphone and store in iphone memory.

Comment: You want to run an apple script on the iPhone??? Are you sure?

Comment: yeah.. thats the requirement

Comment: Impossible! AppleScript does not run on iOS!

Comment: i have tried this script in iphone  but seems captured screenshot couldn't be found since destination folder seems to be set in device memory.How to set destination folder to iphone memory to store in photos album of iphone

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110485/discussion-between-gopinath-and-luk2302).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110539/discussion-between-gopinath-and-luk2302).

Comment: As I stated "AppleScript does not run on iOS!"